Identification of NiMH connector
What kind of connector is this? It's from a NiMH battery.


What are the dimensions of the connectors and the center-to-center distance of the contacts?  The connector looks like it could be proprietary to me.

Thank you for your reply, it's 3.8mm

That's a "pin and socket" connector.
Measure the pitch.

If the pitch is 3.38 mm, then it's a Molex Standard .062 (My Identiconn site).
If the pitch is 5.03 mm, then it's a Molex Standard .093 Pin and Socket 5.03 (My Identiconn site).
If the pitch is 6.3 mm, then it's a Molex Standard .093 Pin and Socket 6.3 (My Identiconn site).

The white male receptacle is a standard part. The black female plug is a custom version of the standard plug in a molded housing.

Thank you for your reply, much appreciated. I measured about 3.8mm pitch, which should be Molex Standard .062. You mentioned the black plug being custom, do you reckon a standard one would fit? If not, how would you recommend making a connection?


do you reckon a standard one would fit?  -- yes.

